# Dynamic generated FontIcon is not displaying correctly (UWP)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I want to put a font icon inside a Grid. If I do it with XAML like this

```
   <FontIcon  Glyph="&#xE96F;"/>
```

It works fine. But when I try to add the same item dynamically it is not working (instead of icon some wiered symbols coming). Dynamic code as follows

```
                    var fic = new FontIcon {Glyph = "&#xE970" };
                    Grid.SetColumn(fic, col);
                    grdSearchResultHeader.Children.Add(fic);
```

dynamically added Output looks like this

[image]

And the Xaml added one looks correct like this

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&#xE970;` is the escaped text and can only be used in XAML (or similar XML). In C# you don’t need to escape, you just need to type `\uE970`.

Thanks.